# Odoo updating or creating nested array with Web Service API (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, odoo, odoo-11

I'm trying to update and create a record with odoo web services using this package https://github.com/robroypt/odoo-client.

But it isn't working with nested array

```
$data = [
   'name' => 'from API2',
   'active' => true,
   'item_ids' => [6, 10]
];

return $this->client->create('product.pricelist',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Many2one` or `Many2many` fields you can simply use :

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'from API2',
    'active' => true,
    'item_ids' => [[6, 0, [6]]]
];
```

Comment: For `Many2one` you just need the ID and for `One2many` (what you probably meant) the tuple `(6, 0, list_of_ids)` can't be used but the tuples with magic number 1 (create a new record with values), 2 (write on an existing record with ID with values), 3 (unlink an existing record with ID) and 4 (link an existing record with ID). 5 (unlink a list of records by IDs) and 6 (link a list of records by IDs) are for `Many2many` fields only.